# Exception handling using Oracle Forms Builder

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am making my first Oracle form in `Oracle Forms Builder` with the help of web material i.e. tutorials etc. I have written the following code in the `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger:

```
INSERT INTO PATIENT VALUES 
(:CNIC_NO, :P_NAME, :CITY, :ADDRESS, :GENDER, :BLOOD_GROUP, :DISEASE, :WARD_NO);
COMMIT;
```

The problem here is that an unhandled exception is raised by the trigger with the following error numbers:

- *ORA-12899* (Reason is the Null value is inserted in non-Null column)
- *ORA-1400*  (Reason is that the data length is too large than the allowed length)

I need to popup an informative message box for these and a default one for the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I would avoid this errors by builtin Oracle forms validation. Set `Required` property to `True` on property panel for all items, which are based on not null database columns. Oracle forms then forces user to enter a value.

Next set `Datatype` and `Maximum length` properties to set basic data validations.

This should be enough in your case. If your still want to catch an exception, use code like this:

```
begin
    INSERT ...
exception
    when others then
        message(DBMSERRTEXT);
end;
```

Anyway - it is not good idea to insert data using when button pressed  triggers. It is not transaction safe. Use standard forms block. Oracle forms does all the data validations and manipulations for you.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the detailed answer. Although I have found the method using code but using forms validation is another nice tip :)

Comment: Be careful using `when others` in forms triggers. It will catch all exceptions, it can be difficult to find errors in code. You will handle more exceptions than you need to.

Comment: It's a while since I used Forms, but one thing I remember clearly is that there are different alert popups available for Error, Information and general Message, and it was a good idea to write a standard set of `pop_error` /`pop_info` etc procedures once and reuse them as needed. For example, the 'error' flavour would stop with failure while the 'info' one would not.

Answer (score 0):

You have either to guarantee there is a suitable value will be inserted in the specified column that doesn't accept null value the you have to use `NVL` function inside the insert statement. Well, it's quite a good idea to have a technique too.
[handle Oracle Forms errors and informative messages](http://oracledevelopertrainingtasks.blogspot.com.eg/2015/05/three-steps-to-informative-messages-in.html)

You have also to construct your table columns size larger enough to store the inserted as the address for example must be larger than 100 varchar2.

Comment: I'm not willing to carefully repair the txtspk every time you re-add it - if you have amendments to make, please ensure you use real words (no "u" meaning "you" for example) and please do not sign your posts. Your sig block is a good enough signature. Code functions are better `FORMATTED()` rather than **BOLDED()** too - use backticks for inline formatting.

Comment: Why it's not free to write the way i like to express myself in shortcut words,etc. who are you?  i don't understand why are you so precise to the answer? where can i find these details to follow?

Comment: For various reasons. Partly, to avoid downvotes, because some people find txtspk irritating. Partly because [spelling and grammar are important](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Partly, because you need to be OK [with other people editing your posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). Partly [because this is the community's opinion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293779). Partly because I've been here for several years and I've absorbed a number of themes about how we like posts to be written.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [The Default Oracle Forms Menu Tool Bar](https://oracledevelopertrainingtasks.blogspot.com/)  will handle the form's CRUD Operations for you. Instead of writing the insert,update,etc.

But, you have to specify using it by yourself for every form module.